# An Exotic Transport Phenomena with Zero-Current at Different Voltage Values

Tags: fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter, research-level, transport-phenomena

I am a researcher working with active matters, and in one of my experiment I've seen a very exotic transport phenomena which we obtain zero-current for many different values of voltage (those values obey an algebraic relation and in theory there are infinitely many of them). I wonder whether there is any analogy to our observation in the more conventional part of physics, e.g. condensed matter physics or hydrodynamics.

Comment: you should add more specifics in order to get any reasonable response. What is the circuit diagram? what is special about the components used? impossible to know what the expected output should be without enough info

Comment: It's not a circuit, it's just the flow of active matters through a long narrow channel. The flux drops close to 0 when the parameter that controls the push is of specific values.